# No module named 'imutils' when installed

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, windows-10, importerror

I know there have been a lot of questions and answers on this matter, but I've tried every method and none seem to work. I'm using `anaconda` on `windows 10-11`. I did `pip install imutils` and it said

```
Collecting imutils
  Using cached imutils-0.5.4-py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: imutils
Successfully installed imutils-0.5.4
```

but then I did `import imutils` and got an error. I have tried doing

- `pip3 install imutils`
- `pip install --upgrade imutils`
- moving the file, but it was in the right spot
- `import pip    pip.main(['install', 'imutils'])`

and many other "solutions." I've been trying to get this to work for a couple of hours now and it just isn't working.

Comment: does it work if you open a python shell by typing `python` in a terminal, then import the library ?

Comment: did you try installing it with conda? `conda install -c conda-forge imutils`

Comment: everytime I try any conda install it does this weird thing with a frozen and flexible resolve and I get an error. I also tried the thing with the python shell, and that didn't work either.

Comment: I take that back; I can import in the shell